# Наречие "мало-мало-мало". Дефис или запятая?

Tags: орфография, наречия, раздельно-дефис

На многих сайтах эта строчка из одной популярной песни пишется так:

**Я схожу с ума, мне мало-мало-мало тебя**.

Почему здесь стоит дефис? Ведь *мало-мало* — это очень мало, как мне кажется, а в предложении подразумевается перечисление слова "мало". Или всегда пишем однотипные наречия через дефис, вне зависимости от смысловой нагрузки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь спорный случай.
С одной стороны, наречия, образованные повторением одинаковых (или однокоренных) слов, пишутся через дефис. Так что дефисное написание имеет как минимум некоторую мотивацию. Правило это формулируется, правда, для двух слов (т.е. одного дефиса), но в данном случае обобщение на большее число членов выглядит вполне естественным. 
Но вот с другой стороны, понимания как перечисления тоже никто не исключал, если слова произносится с паузой. Тогда это не одно сложное наречие, а своеобразный рефрен из нескольких одинаковых.

Но все-таки при прочих равных, если на иное нет явно выраженного авторского мнения, я бы предпочел именно такое написание, через два дефиса.

*Мало-мало - это не "очень мало", это просто "мало", просто акцентированное таким вот образом. Добавление еще одного "мало" сказывается на стилистике, но не на смысле.*

Answer (score 1):

**Мало-мало-мало** — это авторская фигура, при этом дефисное написание соответствует **произношению без пауз**, поэтому больше подходит, да к тому не исключает дополнительную **количественную оценку** (очень мало).

А вообще говоря, обе формы написания используются **для усиления эмоционального воздействия**, между ними нет принципиальной разницы, хотя они произносятся и оформляются графически по-разному.

Читать полностью: [Повтор как выразительное средство поэтической речи (на материале произведений авторов Оренбуржья)](http://www.km.ru/referats/336281-povtor-kak-vyrazitelnoe-sredstvo-poeticheskoi-rechi-na-materiale-proizvedenii-avtorov-orenbur)

1) **Лексический повтор** — это выразительное средство  речи. Основная цель — **усиление** впечатления читателя от того, что изображается; это может быть повышение длительности действия (движения, чувства и т.д).

2) Основная цель **дефисной подачи** — отражение **степени количественной** характеристики изображаемого.