# Запятая или дефис при лексическом повторе?

Tags: лексика, запятые, дефис

Примеры:

> А на сердце опять горячо, горячо.
>
> Весело, весело встретим Новый год!

Говорят, дефис показывает усиление признака (горячо-горячо = очень горячо). А запятая что показывает?

Comment: Был вопрос: [Наречие “мало-мало-мало”. Дефис или запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426820/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f/426843#426843), но информации там недостаточно, а ссылка не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Различие в пунктуационном и орфографическом оформлении сочетаний с повторяющимися глаголами  объясняется присущими этим сочетаниям значениями.

У Розенталя читаем:

1.Между одинаковыми словами, повторяющимися с интонацией перечисления для указания на длительность действия, для обозначения большого числа предметов или явлений, для подчеркивания степени качества и т.п., ставится запятая, например: Но он ехал, ехал, а Жадрина было не видать (Пушкин); Синий, синий, ходит он плавным разливом (Гоголь); И ближе, ближе все звучал грузинки голос молодой (Лермонтов); ...Все это ушло от меня навсегда, навсегда (Фадеев).

Между двумя повторяющимися словами пишется дефис, если образуется сложное слово, обычно с одним логическим ударением. Сюда относятся:

1) имена прилагательные со значением усиления признака: белый-белый (в значении «очень белый»), слабенький-слабенький (в значении «очень слабенький»); ср.: ...Птички уже поют в лесу, заря на востоке, розовая-розовая, воздушная-воздушная, плакать хочется, такая милая заря (В. Панова); разграничение написаний типа белый-белый и синий, синий  можно показать на таких примерах: Житель аула был старый-старый, бог весть сколько ему было лет от роду (в значении «очень старый»). – Старый, старый, а всех вокруг пальца обвел (в значении «старый-то старый, а ...»);

2)глаголы несовершенного вида со значением непрерывности процесса или интенсивности действия: сидел-сидел в напрасном ожидании; просил-просил о помощи; ср.: На самой заре встанешь и топчешься-топчешься по избе: и воды надо принести, и печь растопить...(Паустовский);

3)глаголы совершенного вида со значением действия, ограниченного каким-то отрезком времени: постоял-постояли ушел; ср.: Похожу-похожу по двору, на улицу загляну и опять на печь лягу (Салтыков-Щедрин);

4) вопросительно-относительные местоимения и наречия со значением неопределенного предмета или обстоятельства, которым противопоставляется нечто противоположное: кто-кто, а он обязательно придет; где-где, а здесь всегда достаточно воды; ср.: Уж кто-кто, а вы, женщина, должны уметь оказать помощь в таких случаях (В. Панова); ...Уж кому-кому, а мне-то пора было этому научиться (Каверин); но (при наличии предлога): Уж в ком, в ком, а в нем я вполне уверен;

5)наречия с подчеркнутым выражением присущего им значения: чуть-чуть, едва-едва.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/44.htm#*=*](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/44.htm#_=_)

*А на сердце опять горячо, горячо.*

С помощью лексического повтора подчёркнута степень качества. Если б было через дефис, то это было бы слово состояния со значением "очень горячо", а для автора, видимо, важно именно слово горячо, ведь любовь - горячее чувство. Очень горячо - это жарко, совсем другое ощущение, больше относящееся к страсти, а не к любви.

*Весело, весело встретим Новый год!*

Здесь тоже лексический повтор, а не сложное наречие со значением "очень весело". Просто весело, как бы без фанатизма. Чрезмерно весело - это уже шалости, а праздник для детей должен быть просто весёлый, тогда всё будет хорошо.

Answer (score 3):

Дефис или запятая диктуют интонацию, без всякого сомнения.

Дефис предполагает "скороговорку" - произношение без паузы, придаёт выражению значение "очень-очень".

Запятая требует перечислительной, подчёркивающей, утвердительной интонации, а также паузы. Значения "очень-очень" уже нет.